# Interval containing $\sigma^2$

Tags: normal-distribution

Can someone help mesolving the following problem?

Let $\mu$ be know for a normaly distributed population of 100 individuals. Determine the probability of the random interval $$\left[\frac{Y}{124.34},\frac{Y}{77.93}\right]$$ containing $\sigma^2$, for $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{100}(X_i-\mu)^2$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So as far as I understand we have
$$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$$
where $\mu$ is known and $\sigma$ is unknown. Now, we are trying to find the probability that some quantity falls in some interval
$$P\bigg(\frac{Y}{a}\leq\sigma^{2}\leq\frac{Y}{b}\bigg)$$
with $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\mu)=ns^{2}$ ($s^{2}$ denotes the sample variance) and $b<a$.

From here, we can do some simple manipulation
$$\begin{align}
P\bigg(\frac{ns^{2}}{a}\leq\sigma^{2}\leq\frac{ns^{2}}{b}\bigg)&=P\bigg(\frac{1}{a}\leq\frac{\sigma^{2}}{ns^{2}}\leq\frac{1}{b}\bigg)
\end{align}$$

We know that
$$\frac{ns^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}=G\sim\chi^{2}_{n}$$

and therefore
$$\frac{\sigma^{2}}{ns^{2}}=\frac{1}{G}=G^{*}\sim\text{Inv-}\chi^{2}_{n}$$

So what we are actually asking is what is the probability that an [Inverse Chi-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-chi-squared_distribution) random variable falls in some interval
$$\begin{align}
P\bigg(\frac{1}{a}\leq \frac{1}{G}\leq\frac{1}{b}\bigg)&=P\bigg(\frac{1}{a}\leq G^{*}\leq\frac{1}{b}\bigg)\\
&=F_{G^{*}}(1/b)-F_{G^{*}}(1/a)
\end{align}$$
where $F_{G^{*}}$ is the cumulative distribution function of the Inverse Chi-squared distribution.

Comment: thank you so much!